# SQL error - "Column ambiguously defined"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query data from two tables and keep getting a "Column ambiguously defined" error.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT deptno AS "Dept No", dname AS "Dept Name", sum(sal) AS "Sal Cost" 
FROM emp, dept 
WHERE emp.deptno = dept.deptno 
GROUP BY dname;
```

It is erroring in the select statement.

Comment: deptno is defined in both tables. You need to specify which table that column is coming from in your select clause. Either emp or dept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have more than one table reference in a query, you should always qualify *all* column names.  Then, you'll never get this error again:

```
SELECT d.deptno AS "Dept No", d.dname AS "Dept Name", sum(e.sal) AS "Sal Cost" 
FROM emp e JOIN
     dept d
     ON e.deptno = d.deptno 
GROUP BY d.deptno, d.dname;
```

Note that you have to aggregate by *all* unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`.

I also strongly advise you to use column names that don't require escaping:

```
SELECT d.deptno, d.dname, sum(e.sal) AS salary_cost
. . .
```

Comment: The column *names* don't require escaping. It's just the *aliases* and that's perfectly valid to make shortcut names more readable.

Comment: Aah, I see.  Thank you for your quick response.  The previous error is gone, but I am now getting another error, "not a GROUP BY expression" on the first line.  I feel like I get this error most often whenever I'm trying to use a GROUP BY with more than two columns.

Comment: Aha! I got it.

SELECT d.deptno, d.dname, sum(e.sal) AS salary_cost FROM emp e JOIN dept d ON e.deptno = d.deptno GROUP BY d.dname, d.deptno;

Thanks again!